# Shopping Cart Symfony with two different items

Tags: php, symfony

i have some issues with creating a shopping cart in symfony.
I have to create a shopping cart (reservation system) for a hotel who sell cure and treatment so i have two type of product to add to my cart (two entities: cure and treatment).

**Probleme**

In my Paniercontroller I create i shopping cart where id of each item in the cart is the id of cure (if i add cure ) and id of treatment (id i add treatment) so when i have two item with same id, the new item delete the old one (it possible because cure and treatment can have same id each one of them are in different table)

I went to test if item is cure or treatment before adding to the cart. I also think to create different action for each one but i don't know if that will fix the problem.
If any one have an idea how to do that thank you for help.

this is my Paniercontroller:

```
 public function panierAction()
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    //$session->remove('panier');
    //die();
    if( !$session->has('panier')) $session->set('panier',array());
    var_dump($session->get('panier'));
    die();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cures = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Cure')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('panier')));
    $treatments = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Treatment')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('panier')));
    return $this->render('CmsBundle:Default:reservation-cure-step2.html.twig', array(
        'cures' => $cures,
        'treatments' => $treatments,
        'panier' => $session->get('panier'),
    ));
}
 public function ajouterAction($id)
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    if( !$session->has('panier')) $session->set('panier',array());
    //$panier [id du produit] ==> quantite
    $panier= $session->get('panier');
    if(array_key_exists($id, $panier))
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->query->all() != null )
            $panier[$id] = $this->getRequest()->query->all();

    }else{
        if($this->getRequest()->query->all() != null)
            $panier[$id] = $this->getRequest()->query->all();

        else
             $panier[$id] = 1;
    }
    $session->set('panier',$panier);
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success','élement ajouté avec succés');
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panier'));
}


 public function supprimerAction($id)
{
      $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
      $panier = $session->get('panier');
    if(array_key_exists($id, $panier))
    {
        unset($panier[$id]);
        $session->set('panier',$panier);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success','élement supprimé avec succés');
    }
     return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panier'));
}
```

}

Comment: they should both implement a `ProductInterface` or something like that. They're both products, aren't they? or create a `CartItem` class, which can hold different kind of entities as one of it's properties.

Comment: thank you for your answer yes they're both products. I will test your idea, i hope it work